# What is the proper cross-platform way to run a background thread after execution?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to write code that will allow me to keep Selenium drivers alive in background processes. Or spawn background processes that periodically check for status changes.

The only requirement is that these background drivers hold the selenium drivers alive in a way I can connect to with a remote session (using their URL and session ID) and can be later killed.

The design is that I want to have a registry file. Whenever I launch one of these processes in the background I want the script to exit but a background processes started in a way I can stop it later.

Ideally I am hoping to make it as simple as a PID. So if the registry file just had a PID and I was able to just kill it that would be slick.
I might put other things in this registry like status etc. But PID is the most important.

Where I am hung up on is exactly how I should start this process I intend to have running past the life of my script. Some people use fork() some people use Thread(daemon=True) and I am not sure how either of them would give me a PID I can use to close the process afterwards.

I am aiming for this code to be able to run on my Mac as well as linux.

Which direction should I take?

Comment: Sound like you don't want a thread, but a kind of (micro)service.